# Dictating Chinese text on Windows

Tags: pronunciation, learning, input-methods

Is there any program for Microsoft Windows for dictating Chinese text, that is more accurate than the built-in Microsoft Speech Recognition?

I am aware that there exist some online solution, such as Google dictation in Google Documents, but as far as I know it only allows to dictate within the browser. Dragon NaturallySpeaking doesn't support Chinese.

Answer (score 1):

If you're dual booting into Windows as your primary operating system from Mac OS, you might have more luck with Siri on Mac, which works well for me personally.